# Making polling request in Angular 2 using Observable

Tags: json, angular, observable, rxjs

I have the following code to make a polling GET request in AngularJS 2:

```
 makeHtpGetRequest(){
            let url ="http://bento/supervisor/info";
            return Observable.interval(2000)
                .map(res => res.json()) //Error here
                .switchMap(() => this.http.get(url));

            /*
    This portion works well
    return this.http.get(url)
                .map(res =>res.json());*/
        }
```

TypeScript is giving me an error make the response in JSON format (check comment in the code.

```
TypeError: res.json is not a function
```

Surprisingly, it was working for some time and I am not sure if I changed anything else, but it stopped working.

The commented part in the code works very well.

Answer (score 12):

Try

```
return Observable.interval(2000) 
        .switchMap(() => this.http.get(url))
        .map(res:Response => res.json());
```

Comment: I tried this. It still gives me the error. However, it does the polling in any case.

Answer (score 5):

It might be too late, but it might still help someone.

According to [doc](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html)

> This is not Angular's own design. The Angular HTTP client follows the ES2015 specification for the response object returned by the Fetch function. That spec defines a json() method that parses the response body into a JavaScript object.

I think json function only exists in http's response

I would try

```
return Observable.interval(2000) 
        .switchMap(() => this.http.get(url).map(res:Response => res.json()));
```

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is, don't forget to cleanup you setInveral otherwise it will run forever :

```
let myObservable = new Observable(observer => {
     let count = 0;
     let interval = setInterval(() => {
           observer.next(count++);
  },2000);

 //disposal function
return() => {
   clearInterval(interval);
 }
});


let subscriber = myObservable.subscribe(
  val => console.log(val),
  err => console.log(err),
  _ => console.log('done')
);

subscriber.unsubscribe();
```