# return promise every 1 minute?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2, rxjs

is there any way to return a promise every 1 minute continuously?
i was trying something like this but it returns promise only once at the beginning:

```
    startWork() {

    this.dataService.startPing(details).then((result) => {
      this.timeSlotsRefresh();
    }, (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }
```

and then:

```
startPing() {
let startingTime = new Date();

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

  let source = Rx.Observable.timer(startingTime, 60000).timeInterval().pluck('interval');


  this.Subscription = source
    .subscribe(data => {

          this.http.post('http://localhost:63203/api/Ping', JSON.stringify(this.offlinePings[i]))
            .map(res => res.json())
            .subscribe(data => {
              resolve(data);
            }, (err) => {
              reject(err);
            });
    });
});
```

}

it has to basically inform this function every 1 minute to call `this.timeSlotsRefresh();` to refresh the data, how can i achieve that?

Comment: Why not use `setInterval` instead?

Comment: could you show me an example of that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35592716/making-polling-request-in-angular-2-using-observable

Comment: This is an excellent use case for observables. Why do you want it as a promise?

Comment: i didnt know about this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
@Injectable
class Ping {
  readonly observable = Rx.Observable.interval(60000);
  
  subscribe(...cbs) {
    return this.observable.subscribe(...cbs);
  }
}


@Component
class Foo implements OnInit, onDestroy {
  private subscription = null;
  
  constructor(private ping: Ping) {}
  
  onPing(count) {}
  onPingError(error) {}
  onPingFinish() {}
  
  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.ping.subscribe(
      (...d) => this.onPing(...d),
      (...e) => this.onPingError(...e),
      (...f) => this.onPingFinish(...f)
    );
  }
  
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe()
  }
}
```

`Promise`s are meant to work only once, you may need for something similar to a streaming and `Observable`s could suit better.

using [`rx`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/interval.html) with the [`interval`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/interval.html) operator:

```js
var source = Rx
    .Observable
    .interval(2000 /* ms */)
    .map(id => fetch(`https:\/\/jsonplaceholder.typicode.com\/posts\/${id}`).then(res => res.json()))
;

var subscription = source
  .subscribe(post => console.log('New Post', post))
;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.4.0/Rx.js"></script>
```

Comment: but how to use it to comunicate with outer method like in my code?

Comment: You have to expose the observable itself, without any wrapper. Then, anyone can subscribe to it.

Comment: but then how can i know if the api call was succesful or returned an error?

Comment: edited. You need to have a look on how `rxjs` works. Its documentation is very fine and easy to understand.